# Grails radio button show hidden div with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

My radio button in my _form.gsp is coded as

```
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <g:each in="${locationList}" status="i" var="location">
      <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        ...
        <td><g:radio name="location" value="${location.id}" onclick="showLocInfo(this)" checked="${false}" /></td>
      </tr>
    </g:each>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my hidden div is

```
<div id="locationTable" style="display: none">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>HERES LOCATION INFORMATION</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My create.gsp contains some javascript in the head which currently isn't working

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    jQuery.noConflict();

    function showLocInfo(elem){
      if (elem.checked == "true") { 
        document.getElementById('locationTable').style.display = "block";
      }
      if (elem.checked == "false") { 
        document.getElementById('locationTable').style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

The datepicker works, but the show location info function does not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `showLocInfo`, `elem.checked` is a boolean, not a string.  Since you are using 2 `if` statements, rather than an `if/else`, neither block is executed, resulting in no behavior.

Try using instead:

```
if (elem.checked === true) { 
    // ..
```